# Share app through intent but it is not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, apk

I am making chat app and want to share app via Intent . There are not many solution to the problem please help. here is my code but it is throwing error in start Activity

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

                case R.id.share :


                    ApplicationInfo api = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
                    String apkPatch = api.sourceDir;

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File(apkPatch)));
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "ShareVia"));

                    Toast.makeText(NavigationActivity.this, "shareVia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                case R.id.aboutus :
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "aboutUs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

and this is the error in Run screen

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.chatbox, PID: 19897
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/app/com.example.chatbox-7bck8l1ys2PwFlDmiMFq2w%3D%3D/base.apk exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:2083)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2388)
    at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:977)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10809)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10815)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10794)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1710)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5331)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:675)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5262)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:662)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5660)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5628)
    at com.example.chatbox.NavigationActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(NavigationActivity.java:121)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:170)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(SubMenuBuilder.java:91)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:352)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7257)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7213)
    at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:828)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27921)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7830)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1040)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19897 SIG: 9

Comment: It is better if you share app link in google play ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for new APIs, a file URI scheme is different than its scheme of old APIs. So creating a file using `new File(apkPatch)` will raise this exception for newer APIs.

So, you can pass the String to [`Uri.parse`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#parse(java.lang.String)), not the `File` for solving this instead of using `Uri.fromFile`

So replace the below line of code:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(apkPatch)));
```

With:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(apkPatch));
```

> I have tried your solutions and it works pretty well but the apk file name is base.apk but i want my app name there(Chat Box) instead of base

Now to change the apk file name add below to the intent

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Chat Box.apk");
```

Comment: I have tried your solutions and it works pretty well but the apk file name is base.apk but i want my app name there(Chat Box) instead of base

Comment: @HammasAli please check updated answer .. hope it works now